# How to center an image in a gauge

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to put an image into the center of an gauge (where the 'X' is drawn), can't seem to find where to put the code :/

[image]

Comment: if theres no native support, cant you layer something on there with html/css?

Comment: You can use ((chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight) / 2) and negative half size of image height. The same situation with width.

Answer (score 2):

This works, I change the background color and plot color to transparent

```
   chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 0,
        plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotShadow: false,
        plotBorderWidth: 0
     },
```

I create the div dynamicly so:

```
       <div ng-repeat="number in stats.numbers track by $index" id="s{{$index+1}}" class="number col-sm-3"></div>
```

And the css

```
.number{
   background-image: url("../images/x.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example on how to do it with just html/css (and not via highcharts) Its based on a donut example traight from the highcharts site:

**http://jsfiddle.net/hdnfxz03/**

HMTL (chart and image)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <img src="http://peanutbutterjellytime.net/img/peanut-butter-jelly-time.gif">
</div>
```

CSS (this centers the image over the chart)

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative
    width: 600px; 
    height: 400px
}
#wrapper > img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```